# Java string gets split on Unix

Tags: java, linux, string, unix

I am using String builder to create a string message.

```
StringBuilder outputMessage = new StringBuilder("<env:Envelope xsi:schemaLocation=\"OTC_Matching_FX_1-0       /xmls/OTC/OTC_Matching_FX_1-0.xsd  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/  /xmls/OTC/soap-envelope.xsd  http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation    /xmls/OTC/fpml-main-5-1.xsd\" xmlns:env=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:fpml=\"http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation\" xmlns:mtc=\"OTC_Matching_FX_1-0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">");
```

But when this string is printed out on Unix server, this single line gets split into multiple lines:

Using toString to log the message:

```
LOGGER.info("Output: "+outputMessage.toString());
```

This is the output on Unix:

> `<env:Envelope xsi:schemaLocation="OTC_Matching_FX_1-0       /xmls/OTC/OTC_Matching_FX_1-0.xsd  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envel`
>
> `ope/  /xmls/OTC/soap-envelope.xsd  http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation    /xmls/OTC/fpml-main-5-1.xsd" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" xmlns:mtc="OTC_Matching_FX_1-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3`
>
> `.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

I am unable to understand why this is happening. Why is the string getting split in between characters?

Comment: Have you tried not to use StringBuilder? `String s = new String("your text");`?

Comment: Actually I need to append many other strings to this string hence using StringBuilder

Comment: Have you tried to use `System.out.println(outputMessage.toString())`? How does it output the string?

Comment: yes it prints the string in the same way..but only on unix, inside the ide it prints fine on a single line

Comment: Haveyou tried to use `outputMessage.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");`?

Comment: Have you tried disabling line wrapping in your text viewer?

Comment: Are you using  java.util.logging.Logger?

Comment: Using log4j logger